# Facebook show picture post and change size php API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to show on my site the pictures of my posts on my facebook page.
I use facebook API, my code works but I can not change the size of the images.
The Facebook API sends images to 130x130px.
Can you help me change this?
This is my code :

```
<?php
$page_name  = 'xxxxxxxx';
$page_id    = 'PAGES_TIMELINE';
$app_id     = 'xxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxx';
$limit      = 5;

function load_face_posts($page_id, $page_name, $app_id, $app_secret, $limit, $message_len)
{
    $access_token = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$app_id&client_secret=$app_secret&grant_type=client_credentials";
    $access_token = file_get_contents($access_token); // returns 'accesstoken=APP_TOKEN|APP_SECRET'
    $access_token = str_replace('access_token=', '', $access_token);
    $limit        = 5;
    $data         = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$page_name/posts?limit=$limit&access_token=$access_token");
    $data         = json_decode($data, true);
    $posts        = $data[data];

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($posts); $i++) {
        $idpo  = $posts[$i][id];
        //images
        $data1 = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/$idpo/?fields=picture&access_token=$access_token");
        $data1 = json_decode($data1, true);
        $image = $data1['picture'];

?><img src="<?php
        echo $image;
?>"/>
        <?php
    }
}
load_face_posts($page_id, $page_name, $app_id, $app_secret, $limit, $message_len);
?>
```

Comment: Did you do any research on this, like say https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+feed+get+larger+image …?

Comment: Thanks for your reply by it doesn't work.